# How allow for '.' in an Excel file name when 'saving as' using late binding?

Tags: c#, excel, reflection, late-binding

I just came up with  this issue, we have a library that uses Reflection to manipulate Excel files. When a user is trying to save a file that has a `.` in the file name (eg: `01.02.xls`) it won't include .xls in the saved file (result: `01.02`).

`workbook.GetType().InvokeMember("SaveAs", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, workbook, new Object[] { filepath.Remove(filepath.LastIndexOf(".")), 56 });`

Is there an option that allows `.` inside the file name?

Comment: Try using `Path.Combine(filepath,".xls")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you remove .xls from your filepath with

```
filepath.Remove(filepath.LastIndexOf("."))
```

I just tested this myself, if I use just `filepath` as in

```
workbook.GetType().InvokeMember("SaveAs", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
null, workbook, new Object[] { filepath, 56 });
```

it works for me

Comment: Thanks @ReinerSchaack I thought the same at some point but I believe there is reason for that (may be not a good one), there are so many apps that use this library that I'll need to try to test on all of them first.

Comment: Ok, I believe is because if someone write the file name with an extension different than .xls (such as .xslx) it will have a compatibility issue. But that can be handled, so I'll do as you suggested. Thank you @Rainer